# How to use timer for delay in android

Tags: java, android, timer

I want to apply some delay in my code. In my code, there are buttons and when I click the buttons, timer will start. After 2 seconds, code again continues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: Ok. Here is my problem. This is my code

Comment: sorry I am newbie for stackoverflow. I couldnt find how to post code here

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you are asking some question please provide us with the code that is creating problem.
Now, as per your question is suppose you have used onclicklistener, so to make a break of say 5 seconds there is a proper class provided that is called "Handler".
Now,  i can show you a bit of example,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Handler().postDelay(
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Add your task here
                }
        }
    }, 5000);      //5000 here shows you in milliseconds, so its 5 seconds
```

Comment: So the task will execute after 5 seconds that you will define within run() method. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Ok I am new for this site. I will keep in mind. Also, thanks it works.